# Installing node-expat on windows

Tags: node.js

I would like to install node-expat on my nodejs server. But i can not do it by npm install. So i just copy pasted the 'astro-node-expat-v1.6.0-2-g1fa6c6b' folder into my node-modules folder. But I am unable to fine the 'node-expat.node' file. Can anybody throw some light on this?
If anyone has got this file please help locating it in github so that i can copy them into my folder.

Thanks
Sneha

Answer (score 0):

TooTallNate has a gyp version of it that is *supposed* to work on Node 0.8 on windows. However, I have trouble referencing it in my code. You can find my post and input there.